# Combine join results in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am joining two tables of project details on the project table. The project table does not contain duplicate entries for a project. The table "ProjectDeadLines" may contain two separate rows for a project as project start and end are recorded separately.

Snippet of project table:

| ID | name | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Test Project1 | 100 |
| 111 | Test Project2 | 200 |

Snippet of project deadline table:

| ID | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | start | 2022-03-01 |
| 111 | end | 2022-03-04 |

The desired output would be:

| ID | name | sum | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Test Project | 100 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-04 |

Table "ProjectSubmission" contains the value "sum" in the column "PSU_NetAmount". Table "ProjectDeadLines" contains the values "date" and "type" in the columns "PDL_Date" and "PDL_Name".

The current statement joins everything as desired, but creates two rows for each project if a start and end date are defined.

```
SELECT PRO_ProjectNumber, PRO_Description1, PSU_NetAmount, PDL_Date, PDL_Name
FROM Project
         JOIN ProjectSubmission PS on Project.PRO_PK = PS.PSU_PRO_FK
         JOIN ProjectDeadLines PDL on Project.PRO_PK = PDL.PDL_PRO_FK;
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this desired output with MS-SQL?

Comment: Search Conditional aggregations and/or pivoting. There are literally 1,000's of examples of both.

Comment: And which row from ProjectDeadLines do you desire to include in your resultset? What logic do you propose to filter that information? I now see you want both - so conditional aggregation will do that for you.

Comment: Use lead and partition by Id to get the end days and use row_number equal 1 to get the first occurrence

Answer (score 1):

use aggregation

```
SELECT PRO_ProjectNumber, PRO_Description1,sum(PSU_NetAmount), 
min(case when type='start' then PDL_Date end) start_date, 
 max(case when type='end' then PDL_Date end) as end_date,
 PDL_Name
FROM Project
JOIN ProjectSubmission PS on Project.PRO_PK = PS.PSU_PRO_FK
 group by PRO_ProjectNumber, PRO_Description1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT PRO_ProjectNumber, PRO_Description1, PSU_NetAmount, PDLs.PDL_Date, PDLe.PDL_Date
FROM Project
         JOIN ProjectSubmission PS on Project.PRO_PK = PS.PSU_PRO_FK
         JOIN ProjectDeadLines PDLs on Project.PRO_PK = PDL.PDL_PRO_FK AND type='start'
         JOIN ProjectDeadLines PDLe on Project.PRO_PK = PDL.PDL_PRO_FK AND type='end'
;
```